# eclipse orion with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, eclipse-orion

I tried to install eclipse orion with help of npm with the following command:

```
$ export NODE_MODULES=/home/x/apps/node_modules
$ npm install --prefix /home/x/apps/node_modules orion
...
> ws@0.4.27 install /home/x/apps/node_modules/orion/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/-/mime-1.2.6.tgz
make: Entering directory `/home/x/apps/node_modules/orion/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory `/home/x/apps/node_modules/orion/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
orion@0.0.20 apps/node_modules/orion
├── deferred-fs@0.1.0
├── sax@0.4.3
├── rimraf@2.1.4 (graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── connect@2.4.6 (fresh@0.1.0, pause@0.0.1, bytes@0.1.0, cookie@0.0.4, crc@0.2.0, debug@0.7.2, formidable@1.0.11, qs@0.5.1, send@0.0.4)
├── node-inspector@0.2.0-beta4 (async@0.2.6, connect@2.7.3)
└── socket.io-client@0.9.16 (xmlhttprequest@1.4.2, uglify-js@1.2.5, active-x-obfuscator@0.0.1, ws@0.4.27)
```

However, I was not able start orion with the following command:

```
$ npm start orion
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/home/x/node_modules/orion/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.9.0-sabayon
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start" "orion"
npm ERR! cwd /home/x
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.13
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.2
npm ERR! path /home/x/node_modules/orion/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/x/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start', 'orion' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.2
3 info using node@v0.10.13
4 error Error: ENOENT, open '/home/x/node_modules/orion/package.json'
5 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
5 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
5 error or email it to:
5 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
6 error System Linux 3.9.0-sabayon
7 error command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start" "orion"
8 error cwd /home/x
9 error node -v v0.10.13
10 error npm -v 1.3.2
11 error path /home/x/node_modules/orion/package.json
12 error code ENOENT
13 error errno 34
14 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

solution: npm start --prefix /home/x/apps/node_modules orion